# How to use countif formula with split ranges?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I need a countif formula which counts the number of cells that contains H. However all the cells are not next to each other.

My current Countif formula is:

```
=countif(E40,"H")*8+countif(E39,"H")*9+countif(E21:E26,"H")*9+countif(E27:E29,"H")*8+......and it     goes on for around 20 iterations.
```

Is there a way of combining all the countif (*9) and the same for the (*8) formulas into one.

I have tried to define names. I also tried countifs

Comment: Can you post a screenshot your of your sample data? What is significance of multiplying by `8` or `9`.

Comment: Are all your cells in column E? What do you mean it goes on for 20 iterations? 20 more specific countifs? or different columns? And how do you decide if you multiply by 8 or 9?

Comment: Look into `=LEN(A1)-len(subsritute(A1,"H",""))`

Comment: There are more countif formula. All are in column e.
The sheet is a monthly hours spreadsheet sorted by employee name each with a different contract of holiday entitlement. The significance of the multiplication sum is how many hours are allocated to each holiday. 
The current formula works but amending it for new beginners/ leavers is sometimes a headache

Comment: Group ranges with VSTACK, something like =VSTACK(E40,E27:E29), then look for "H": =SUM(N(VSTACK(E40,E27:E29)="H"))

Comment: If you were prepared to enumerate, thus hard-coding, all of the individual row numbers then you could use `=9*SUMPRODUCT((ROW(E21:E40)={21,22,23,24,25,26,39})*(E21:E40="H"))+8*SUMPRODUCT((ROW(E21:E40)={27,28,29,40})*(E21:E40="H"))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you were open to using defined names you might consider using a named (array) constant:
[image: screenshot illustrating named-constant based approach]

This is equivalent to using a column of helper cells, without actually doing so (if you *were* prepared to use helper cells then you *would* be able to use `COUNTIFS()`, since it requires ranges for arguments, whereas `SUMPRODUCT` is not so constrained).